# NuGet Packages do not compile Azure CSX

Tags: azure, azure-functions, nuget-package, csx

I have included a NuGet Package in an Azure Function app that I downloaded to work on in Visual Studio. I have added it to the project.json and I still get "error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'NetTopologySuite' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)". I've read through [microsoft's documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-csharp#using-nuget-packages) and cannot find what I could be doing wrong.

Here is a sample of what my csx looks like:

```
#r "System.Data"

using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Net;
using NetTopologySuite;

public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run(HttpRequestMessage req, TraceWriter log)
{
    \\ Code to retrieve data from database and turn it into an array
    \\ of GeoJSON features called DataFromDatabase not shown


    NetTopologySuite.Features.Feature[] TrailSegments = DataFromDatabase;


    HttpResponseMessage resp = req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    resp.Content = new StringContent(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(DataFromDatabase), System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
    return resp;
}
```

Here is my project.json:

```
{
  "frameworks": {
    "net46": {
      "dependencies": {
        "NetTopologySuite.IO.GeoJSON": "1.14.0"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Does anyone have more experience with this that could offer a little more than what's in the documentation?

```
"FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION": "~1"
"WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION": "6.5.0"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do upload the `project.json` file to your function folder(not function app folder), what you have done is exactly right. I have followed your steps and things work fine on my side.

Nuget restoring for function editable online is not so sensitive, so you may wait for a while(you can do some edit in function code and click save or directly restart whole function app).

After that, you can see a `project.lock.json` under the function folder. It means the package has been installed successfully. Then everything goes well.

**Update** for multiple functions sharing reference.

One function package restore can't be used by others. So we have to upload dlls manually if you don't want to add `project.json` to every function. See [shared assemblies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-csharp#referencing-custom-assemblies).

1. Download [NetTopologySuite.IO.GeoJSON](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NetTopologySuite.IO.GeoJSON/).
2. Find four dlls(`NetTopologySuite.dll/NetTopologySuite.IO.GeoJSON.dll/GeoAPI.dll/PowerCollections.dll`) in package and upload them to a `bin` folder under function app folder.
3. Add four assemblies in code like `#r "..\bin\NetTopologySuite.IO.GeoJSON.dll"`. You may also need add `#r "Newtonsoft.Json"` as it's one dependency in that package.
4. If you use the dll with namespace like `NetTopologySuite.Features.Feature[]`, you don't have to import namespaces. And vice versa.

If you know those dependencies clearly, you can only upload and reference dlls you need.

Comment: thank you. I moved it to the folder of the first function and it compiled with no errors. But I have a follow up question. I have multiple functions in the app. I cannot add a project.json to each functions folder. So how does the rest of the app become aware of this. Do I use the #load project functionality?

Comment: @GreenGeo Have updated my answer, see whether it's what you want.

Comment: This did it. I really appreciate your help. I was really struggling there.

Answer (score 0):

I see that you are using 3rd party library which is widely available in Nuget official repository. In such cases, you need to let Azure know which Nuget repository your package, 'NetTopologySuite' resides in..

```
Github: https://github.com/NetTopologySuite/NetTopologySuite
NuGet v3: https://www.myget.org/F/nettopologysuite/api/v3/index.json
NuGet v2: https://www.myget.org/F/nettopologysuite/api/v2
```

1. Create Nuget.config file
2. Add the following contents in that file and re-configure it for your environment.

Nuget.config content - you can find exhaustive file online.

[image]